# Diff comparison and output to separate file

Tags: rhel, diff

I want to compare multiple files with single master file and save it to separate file and also i want one csv file to mention the hostname with status column as change or no change. something bit urgent. Any helping hand here. Thanks.

Below is my inventory file,

```
cat inventory
[routers]
iLAB-SR-12-R2 ansible_host=192.168.82.211
iLAB-SR-12-R3 ansible_host=192.168.82.212
iLAB-SR-12-R4 ansible_host=192.168.82.213
```

Below is my script,

```
#!/bin/bash
config_location="/etc/ansible/backups"
master="/etc/ansible/master.txt"
cd $config_location
file=`ls -l | grep "^-" | awk '{print $NF}'`
for i in $file
do
  diff -c $i $master > "/etc/ansible/difference/diff_$i"
done
```

The above is my script for comparing multiple file with single file and save it to different location as different file names. Now the cust says they don't want to view all the file, they just want to check if there is any difference on files. so they asking some csv file with hostname and comments. 
Ex:

```
Hostname comments 
host1    no changes 
host2    changes
```

Change and no changed depends on diff comparison if it have any difference it says as changes or no difference says no changes
If we see the comments as changes only, the customer will check the file.

Comment: The question is unclear, at least to me. You might want to expand it a bit with a small example of what you are looking for. E.g. what hostname are you talking about? That came completely out of the blue. When you say "... save it to separate file ..." what is "it" that you want to save? How is the csv file related to anything else in the question?

Comment: Please *edit the question* and add your script there (nicely formattted). Do not use comments for that purpose.

Comment: And add the additional information *to the question*: comments can disappear unpredictably.

Comment: Nick, I have amended the question. Thanks.

Comment: Much better, thank you. I edited the question to fix the formatting of the code. It's still not clear however where the hostname is supposed to come from: is it part of the filenames that you compare?

Comment: Hostname comes from inventory file,
...
# cat inventory
[routers]
iLAB-SR-12-R2 ansible_host=192.168.82.211
iLAB-SR-12-R3 ansible_host=192.168.82.212
...
At finally, the hostname and IP address will pull from this inventory but the comments come from diff output.

Comment: ... and I feel like a broken record :-) You should edit the question and add *ALL* relevant information there. In any case, I provided an answer which you can modify for your purposes.

Comment: Sorry for missing that information. I have updated everything in question. Sorry for that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming the filename is (related to) the hostname you mention, you could do something like this in your `for` loop:

```
...
for i in $file
do 
  if diff -c $i $master > "/etc/ansible/difference/diff_$i" ;then
    echo "$i is the same as $master"
  else
    echo "$i is different from $master"
  fi
done
```

`diff` exits with success (status = 0) if the files are the same and exits with failure  (status = 1) if the files are different, so you can use that to check with an `if-else-fi` as above. This code assumes no trouble: it does not check whether some other error has occurred.

You can trivially change the messages the program prints out to csv messages and redirect the output to a file like this:

```
...
echo "Hostname, comments" > output.csv
for i in $file
do 
  if diff -c $i $master > "/etc/ansible/difference/diff_$i" ;then
    echo "$i, no change"
  else
    echo "$i, some change"
  fi
done >> output.csv
```

Comment: Sorry - I don't understand what you are saying. Add an example to your question of what these files look like and maybe somebody will be able to help.

Comment: Okay let say I have 2 hosts host1, host2  and 1 master text file. Now i compare host1 config file with master and host2 config with master.
Now if there is any difference between host1 config & master means i want the output in csv as "some change".
If there is no difference between host1 config & master means i want as output inn csv as "No change".

Comment: I think that's what my answer does.

Comment: Ya offcourse i understand. But i don't know how to save the output to csv file with details. Thanks for your much help Nick.

Comment: Hi Nick, Excellent I have tested your above amended script and its working like a charm. Thanks for your valuable help and spending time with me. GBY.